# How to specify range >2GB for HttpWebRequest in .NET 3.5

Tags: c#, .net, vb.net, httpwebrequest, addrange

I'm building this class to download files in parts/sections/segments. In .NET 4.0, I can use this code to specify the range to download from

```
long startPos = int.MaxValue+1;
HttpWebRequest.AddRange(startPos);
```

and it works because there is a long overload for the AddRange method.

When I looked up the .NET 3.5 version, I realised the `AddRange()` method allows using `int` only.

The possible workaround would be using the [`AddRange(string, int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y9887yx%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) or [`AddRange(string, int, int)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t2c579zy%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) methods. Since the class will have to work in .NET 3.5, I'll have to go with the string specification but unfortunately I can't seem to find any sample code that shows how to specify ranges using this procedure in .NET 3.5. Can anyone show be how to do this?

Thanks.

**Update**

As the first code sample I wrote shows, I would like to specify a range of type `long` instead of `int`. Using type `int` allows requesting for byte ranges only up to 2GB but `long` allows requesting for byte ranges beyong 2GB.

The question therefore is: *How do I specify byte ranges of 2GB or higher on `HttpWebRequest` in .NET 3.5?*

Answer (score 5, accepted):

This is the code by *Mutant_Fruit* copied from [WebRequest.AddRange - what about files > 2gb?](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?p=1794639) showing how to to add a range specifier longer than 2GB to an HttpWebRequest.

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(WebHeaderCollection).GetMethod
                        ("AddWithoutValidate", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);

HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create ("http://www.example.com/file.exe");

long start = int32.MaxValue;
long end = int32.MaxValue +  100000;

string key = "Range";
string val = string.Format ("bytes={0}-{1}", start, end);

method.Invoke (request.Headers, new object[] { key, val });
```

I wrote this extension method for it.

```
#region HttpWebRequest.AddRange(long)
static MethodInfo httpWebRequestAddRangeHelper = typeof(WebHeaderCollection).GetMethod
                                        ("AddWithoutValidate", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
/// <summary>
/// Adds a byte range header to a request for a specific range from the beginning or end of the requested data.
/// </summary>
/// <param name="request">The <see cref="System.Web.HttpWebRequest"/> to add the range specifier to.</param>
/// <param name="start">The starting or ending point of the range.</param>
public static void AddRange(this HttpWebRequest request, long start) { request.AddRange(start, -1L); }

/// <summary>Adds a byte range header to the request for a specified range.</summary>
/// <param name="request">The <see cref="System.Web.HttpWebRequest"/> to add the range specifier to.</param>
/// <param name="start">The position at which to start sending data.</param>
/// <param name="end">The position at which to stop sending data.</param>
public static void AddRange(this HttpWebRequest request, long start, long end)
{
    if (request == null) throw new ArgumentNullException("request");
    if (start < 0) throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException("start", "Starting byte cannot be less than 0.");
    if (end < start) end = -1;

    string key = "Range";
    string val = string.Format("bytes={0}-{1}", start, end == -1 ? "" : end.ToString());

    httpWebRequestAddRangeHelper.Invoke(request.Headers, new object[] { key, val });
}
#endregion
```

The extension methods above need the following `using` directives

```
using System.Reflection;
using System.Net;
```

And there is no need to use this this extension method in .NET 4 because there are two overloads of the [`AddRange`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.addrange%28v=VS.100%29.aspx) method that accept `int64` (`long`) as parameters.

Answer (score 2):

Since .NET 4, `HttpWebRequest.AddRange()` supports long:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd992108.aspx

Answer (score 1):

I believe [the documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/3y9887yx%28v=VS.90%29.aspx) gives some insight into that:

> An example of a Range header in an
>   HTTP protocol request that requests
>   the first 100 bytes would be would be
>   the following:

```
Range: bytes=-99\r\n\r\n
```

> For this example, the rangeSpecifier
>   parameter would be specified as
>   "bytes" and the range parameter would
>   be -99.

Then there is also this from [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_HTTP_header_fields):

```
Range
Request only part of an entity. Bytes are numbered from 0.
Range: bytes=500-999
```

So the code that you would result on the example above is

```
HttpWebRequest.AddRange("bytes", 500, 999);
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt reply. I think I did not make my question too clear. I've updated the question now to reflect what I want to do.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, you do not have enough int and long. But operator overloading only int?

Use headers.

```
httpWebRequest.Headers.Add("Range", "bytes=500-999");
```

Comment: Thanks. I'll try this and let you know what happens.

Comment: I followed your recommendation and met a stumbling block; `Range` headers cannot be added to httpWebRequest so I googled the exception I was getting [(Search results from google)](http://goo.gl/KkD7f) and I found [a post on the MSDN HttpWebRequest.AddRange page](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.httpwebrequest.addrange%28v=vs.90%29.aspx) by **Kris H** that directed me to [a workaround](http://www.codeguru.com/forum/showthread.php?p=1794639). I've posted the workaround in my answer to this question.  Thanks for pointing me in the right direction.