# Using .NET HttpWebRequest, how do I add a Range header with a single number?

Tags: .net, http-headers, httpwebrequest

I'm trying to interface with a [REST interface](https://www.digital-loggers.com/rest.html) where there's a named Range header that takes a single value, not a from and to value. I.e., it takes:
`Range: dli-depth=1`
not
`Range: dli-depth=0-1`

I can use [HttpWebRequest.AddRange()](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.httpwebrequest.addrange?view=netframework-4.8) to add the Range header to my HttpWebRequest, but no matter which variant I pick, I always end up with a dash in the value to the right of the equals sign. The device in question won't accept a Range header with a dash in the value. If I attempt to add `Range` as a custom header:

```
myRequest.Headers.Add("Range", $"dli-depth={depth}");
```

...I get this exception:

```
System.ArgumentException: 'The 'Range' header must be modified using the appropriate property or method.
```

How do I add this (perhaps non-standard) Range HTTP header in .NET?

Comment: Try this hack https://stackoverflow.com/a/6580033/1099716

Comment: That worked perfectly. Thanks! Care to add that as answer? My question isn't exactly the same as the one you referenced, but the answer is the same.

Comment: Great, I've added answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you have non-standard header, .net won't allow you to add this header.
You can use the following [hack](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6580033/1099716):

```
MethodInfo method = typeof(WebHeaderCollection).GetMethod
                        ("AddWithoutValidate", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic);
HttpWebRequest request = (HttpWebRequest) WebRequest.Create(<your url>);
string key = "Range";
string val = $"dli-depth={depth}";
method.Invoke (request.Headers, new object[] { key, val });
```